# Analytic (sub)variety and connected components

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am trying to figure out the proof of Bertini's theorem in Griffiths-Harris book on Principles of Algebraic Geometry, page 138:

> But by the calculation above, the ratio $f/g$ is constant on every connected component of $V-B$ and so $V$ can meet only finitely many divisors $D_{\lambda}$ away from the base locus of $\{D_{\lambda}\}$...

I would like to know why is this the case. Is it because an analytic (sub)variety has only finitely many connected components?  If it is true, kindly give some references. Thanks!